# Dynamic select menu at rails4. does not work ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I tried to use dynamic select menu.
But, ajax does not work. please help me.
So, I wrote these code at /app/views/compares/show.hmtl.erb.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeMaker(){
      var select = document.getElementById('maker');
      var options =  document.getElementById('maker').options;
      var value = options.item(select.selectedIndex).value;

      $.ajax({
           url: "/compares/change_select",
           type: "GET",
           data: '&maker=' + value
      })
}

function changeModel(){
      var select = document.getElementById('model');
      var options =  document.getElementById('model').options;
      var value = options.item(select.selectedIndex).value;

      $.ajax({
           url: "/compares/change_select",
           type: "GET",
           data: '&model=' + value
      })
}
</script>

<%= form_for(@compare,url:{controller: :compares,action: :searching}) do |f| %>
    <p>
      <label for="maker">Maker:</label>
      <%= collection_select :car,:maker, Car.all,:maker,:maker,{prompt:"Maker"},{onchange:"changeMaker();"} %>
    </p>
    <p id="classList">
    <label for="model">Model:</label>


    <%= render :partial => 'classList_body' %>
</P>


    <%= f.submit "yo",class:"btn" %>
<% end %>
```

and wrote some code at the same directory.as a "_classList_body.html".

```
<p><%= @models %></p>
<p><%= @makers %></p>
<%= collection_select :car,:model,@models,:model,:model,{prompt:"Model"},{onchange:"changeModel()"} %>
```

and also wrote this code.this is also at the same directory.

```
$("#classList").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'classList_body', :models => @models, :makers => @makers) %>");
```

Comment: did you get any response in your partial "_classList_body.html"  ?